# Use Table View As Picker

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

In my iOS app i have one view controller that handles my main view. If i have a button on that view can i have it open up a modal table view so the user can select a row from the table and then a label on the main view is equal to the selected row text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it's possible. You could use the method, presentViewController:animated:completion:, to present a modal table view controller. The main view controller has a property, presentedViewController which gives you access to that controller (the one you're presenting) so you can get the value of one of its properties (which would be set to the text of the selected row).

After Edit:

You can do it this way. In the presenting view controller have this:

In the init method (or viewDidLoad) register to receive a notification with this line:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dismissAndUpdate:) name:@"ItemSelectedNotification" object:nil];
```

Then these 2 methods:

```
 -(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {
    RDTableViewController *tvc = [[RDTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self presentViewController:tvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}


-(void)dismissAndUpdate:(NSNotification *) aNotification {
    self.label.text = [aNotification.userInfo valueForKey:@"selectedText"];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

And here is an example of what can be done in the table view controller subclass:

```
@implementation RDTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style]) {
        self.theData = @[@"one",@"two",@"three",@"foour",@"five",@"six"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.theData.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"NewCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"NewCell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.theData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
    return cell;
}

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[self.theData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"selectedText"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ItemSelectedNotification" object:self userInfo:dict];
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. Now where will i put this table view in a separate view?

Comment: @Cristian, You create a table view controller subclass, which will automatically create a table for you.  No need for a xib file unless you're doing something fancy.

Comment: ok thanks so in my main view controller i reference "CustomViewController.h" and i use this code to show the table
 
CustomFileViewController *viewController = [[CustomFileViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

from here how can i get the selected row data?

Comment: You need to use UITableViewDelegate methods  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
 //Pass the indexPath.row to mainView
if (indexPath.row==0) {
 mainButton.text = @"setTextToButton";
}


}

Comment: Hi thanks for the edit it looks promising but i have a small problem
(ViewController *) seems to give me an error. What should i put here? I get this error
[UITabBarController dismissAndUpdate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9adaca0
is this because my views are in a tab bar? I need the data sent back to the view that send it not the tab bar.

Comment: ViewController is the name of my class that has the window with the button, and is the one presenting the modal view.  You should substitute whatever is the name of your class that's serving this purpose. Remember to import the header for that class into your table view controller class.

Comment: @rdelmar Hi, Thanks i did change it to the class with the button but for some reason it is trying to call dismissAndUodate on my tab bar controller because my views are in a tab bar.

Comment: If you log self.presentingViewController does it give you the tab bar controller?  It's hard for me to tell what's going on without knowing the class structure of your project.

Comment: @rdelmar Hi when i log that it gives me the main tab bar controller instead of the controller that is called it to open.

Comment: In your original post, you mention a button.  Is that in the view of one of the tab bar controllers view controllers or are you talking about one of the tabs at the bottom?  I really can't figure out what's going on here without knowing the structure of your app.  If it's not too proprietary, you could send me the project, and I'll have a look at it.  My email address is listed on my profile.

Comment: Hi i couldn't see your email but i took some screen shots to show you what i have. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/853/50032428.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/834/65276222.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/705/54005455.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/542/32265456.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/526/84204185.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/195/50771902.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/33/18528697.png/

Comment: i have a tabbar and in that tab bar there is a send tab with a button send file. when i press send file i want a table view to show that uses customfileviewcontroller because that populates the view. When the user selects a row i want that row sent back to the send tab.

Comment: If you can, send me the project and I'll look at it a little later.  I've got to go work on my deck project (as in a real deck, not an app).  - rdelmar@comcast.net

Comment: @Cristian, I did some more exploring, and when using a tab bar controller, I got the same results you did -- I don't know if this is a bug, or the way it's supposed to be. Maybe, since the tab bar controller presents all the other view controllers, it's the presenter of any modal views as well.  Anyway, I've updated my answer to use a notification to let the presenting view controller know that a selection has been made.  I think this should now work for you (remember to change the declaration of dismissAndUpdate: because the parameter is now a notification).

Comment: @rdelmar Wow i cant thank you enough it works perfectly, i just have one question. When i log the output i get:

2012-08-14 18:37:12.712 Share Me[48014:c07] file://localhost/Users/me/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.0/Applications/B0983D71-E28B-44EE-905D-46B7B1605FBA/Documents/New%20York%20Yankees.jpg
^This is logged twice, couldn't fit it in this comment and this:

2012-08-14 18:37:12.721 Share Me[48014:c07] Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <UITabBarController: 0x8b9d400> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!

Comment: @Cristian I'm not sure what that means. IT sounds like the tab bar controller is trying to dismiss something too.  I didn't see anything like that in my test app. Please accept my answer, I think this is all I can do.

Comment: @rdelmar I hope this is clearer, In the dismissandUpdate i put an NSLog which logs the selectedText. But it logs it twice.

Comment: Hmmm.... I can't see why that would happen.  There must be something different in the structure of you app, than the test one that I made.

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this

add a tableview to u r view controller, create a object to tableview.

Then after do like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
 tableViewObj.hidden = YES;
array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"label1",@"label2",@"label3",@"label4", nil];  
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
displayText.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
tableViewObj.hidden = YES;
}

-(IBAction)gotoBack:(id)sender
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:tableViewObj cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
tableViewObj.hidden = NO;
}
```

i think may be it is useful to u

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion but i was planning on using a modal view only because it is presented with an animation.

Comment: so better you can apply animation to tableview

Answer (score 0):

```
You can handle those values by using UITableViewDelegate methods . By getting the selectedIndex path value set the text to Button.<br/>

  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MainView : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *mainButton;

}  
 @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *mainButton;

//in MainView.m file 
@synthesize mainButton;



 //in CustomViewController.h file 
     #import "MainView.h"
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface CustomViewController :UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> {

     IBOutlet UITableView *tableList;

    }


    //in .m file 

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
     //Pass the indexPath.row to mainView
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
MainView *mainV = [[MainView alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];
            mainV.mainButton.text=@"setMainButtonText";
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainV animated:YES];

    }
  ///By using indexPath you can set that value ..


    }
```